# How do you check if your configuration for Azure Search is working on Sitecore 8.2.7?

Tags: sitecore-client, configuration, azure, xconnect, azure-search

According to this official guide "Configure Azure Search"(https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search#_Create_a_Search), first I have created Search Service on Azure.

Secondly, I have disabled all the config files for Solr and enabled config files for Azure Search. Then, I added a single code with URL and API ver, key in ConnectionStrings.config file.

So what can I do next? I cannot see any guides about how to test the connections between Sitecore and Azure Search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Content Management server, log in and go to the Control Panel, open the Indexing manager and then Rebuild all indexes. If you don't get any errors then you can check the indexes in Azure search and make sure the count of items indexed is as expected. Even if it succeeds you should check the logs for any warnings and errors that may cause some individual items not to be indexed.